# File Handling and making directories to match in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, matching, file-handling

I have these files: `File_1.2.txt`, `File_1.5.txt`, `File_2.3.txt`, and `File_4.7.txt`.

I want to make directories for them and sort them into the directories, like below.

```
Dir_001 -> File_1.2.txt File_1.5.txt 

Dir_002 -> File_1.2.txt File_2.3.txt

Dir_003 -> File_2.3.txt 

Dir_004 -> File_4.7.txt 

Dir_005 -> File_1.5.txt 

Dir_007 -> File_4.7.txt
```

So a directory is made for each number used by the files and all files containing the matching number of the directory are sorted into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# If there are no files match File_*.*.txt
# replace File_*.*.txt by empty string
shopt -s nullglob 

for i in File_*.*.txt; do
  echo "processing file $i"
  IFS="_." read foo num1 num2 foo <<< "$i"
  printf -v dir1 "Dir_%03d" "$num1"
  printf -v dir2 "Dir_%03d" "$num2"
  mkdir -pv "$dir1" "$dir2"
  cp -v "$i" "$dir1"
  cp -v "$i" "$dir2"
done
```

Comment: Could you give me a brief description of the line IFS="_." read foo num1 num2 foo <<< "$i"

Comment: This line use `_` and `.` as field separators and split string (e.g.) `File_1.2.txt` from $i in four parts. Useless `File` to $foo, `1` to $num1, `2` to $num2 and useless `txt` overwrite $foo again to avoid a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least have tried this yourself.  Just copying other people's code is not a good way of learning.

There are several ways of doing this, here is mine, where is yours?

```
#!/bin/bash

function make_dir
{
    #name="Dir00$1"
    # Cribbed from the answer given by @Cyrus
    printf -v name "Dir_%03d" "$1"

    echo "$name"
    if [[ ! -d $name ]]
    then
        mkdir "$name"
    fi
}

# I don't need an array here, but I have no idea where these filenames come from
filenames=(File_1.2.txt File_1.5.txt File_2.3.txt File_4.7.txt)

for fname in ${filenames[@]}
do
    for seq in {1..999}      # No idea what the upper limit should be
    do
        #if [[ $fname == *$seq* ]]
        # Edit: to handle multi-character sequences
        if [[ $fname == *[_.]$seq.* ]] 
        then
            dir=$(make_dir $seq)
            cp "$fname" "$dir"
        fi
    done
done
```

Others will no doubt improve on this.

EDITs to the function and the sequence.

Comment: This is great! I had no idea where to start and had been trying stuff for the past few hours but it wasn't working out. The only question I have is, how can I use something like printf or sprintf at name="Dir00$1" so once I have  10 or more directories it's Dir010 instead of Dir0010.

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer:  look at the answer that Cyrus gave, that should give you a clue.  I hesitate to use his method because that would be plagiarism.  You should increase the sequence in `{1..7}` - you did not mention numbers > 7 in your question,

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer: replace `name="Dir00$1"` by `printf -v name "Dir_%0.3d" "$1"`.

Comment: @cdarke: It's a bug. The dot is useless. Thank you.

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer: guess what?  Now you ARE a programmer.  Come, join us, do not be afraid, become one of us (one of us, one of us, one of us ...).

Comment: @cdarke: I just noticed that in directory Dir_001 contains anything containing a "1" such as 11, 12 ect... What would be the most effective way around this?

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer:  OK, that possibility was not described - sorry but your specification was not particularly clear on that.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @ChemistnotaProgrammer: edit done to handle multi-character sequences